# rails show category select box and redirect based on the selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, categories, has-and-belongs-to-many, grouped-collection-select

i am trying to find a way in which a select box is populated with categories and when the user selects a category and submits, they are redirected to the selected categories page which show all listings tagged with that category.

basically its an habtm relationship, where listings has_and_belongs_to_many categories and vice versa, and through the categories controller, all category is listed in a select box in the index view and a selection of any particular category should redirect to show all listings in that category.

this is what i have in category index page

```
<ul>
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <li><%= link_to category.name, category_path(category) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<%= form_for :categories, :url => {:action => :show}, :method => "get" do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= collection_select(:name, :id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

on submitting, only url updates itself. like this - localhost:3000/categories?utf8=%E2%9C%93&name%5Bid%5D=1&commit=Submit

tried to do with ul list, it works. but cant work it out with select box list

categories controller

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all
end

def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end
```

what is wrong

**UPDATE**

hey i made this sql to sort -

```
def show     

@Category = Category.find_by_sql ["select place from listings l , categories c, categories_listings cl where c.id = cl.category_id and l.id = cl.listing_id and name in (?,?)" ,  params[:name][:id] , params[:name][:id]]

end
```

in the index page,i updated the form  -

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= collection_select(:name, :id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= collection_select(:name, :id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
```

show page

```
<ul>
  <% @Category.each do |c| %>
    <li><%= c %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

-the select boxes are not mapping to the correct param and is mapping only to the second select, which yields no result. how can i correct this or am i doing it correct

Answer (score 0):

You're probably having some trouble with routes.
If you're doing `resources :categories` in routes.rb, the route for categories#show is /categories/:id so your form will actually be pointing to categories#index.

That is, with your current setup, id should be part of the URL instead of a form parameter.

Try adding `get 'categories/show' => 'categories#show'` to your routes. It's not as nice as the default route, bur it might fix your problem.

Comment: now it does show me the index page but when submitting it says - Couldn't find Category with id=show..request parameter shows this -                      {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "name"=>{"id"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "id"=>"show"}... i guess collection select is not passing the correct id to the controller??

Comment: hey i was able to solve this by changing the params hash to [:name][:id]. now with two select boxes, how tell the controller to match listings which have one of the two categories??

Comment: As for your first comment, you should add the route before the resources :categories. Routes are evaluated in the order they are declared, and you want it to look for /categories/show before /categories/:id.

Comment: Your second comment... hmm... maybe the easiest way would be to do `@category = Category.find(params[:id]); @category2 = Category.find(params[:id2])` if it's only 2 categories. Otherwise, you could setup your form with an array of ids.

Comment: hey i made this sql to sort . pls look into the updated question here

Comment: You're purring the same param name for both selects! change one of them to :id2 for instance. That SQL is unnecessary, though... You could just do Category.where(:id => [...])

Comment: can you elaborate on the sql?